# Spring - Including current user in every call to Service/DAO Layer

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm performing a business validation : whether current user has permission on particular set of data in the Data Base. For this to perform, I require the user name of logged in user.

The below sample works fine, in which after successful authentication in controller/interceptor, the "userName" parameter is passed in all calls from the controller to service layer.

```
@Service 
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyDAO myDAO;

    public String getData(String userName) {
          return myDAO.getData(userName);
    }
}
```

From controller the User Information is being passed to the Service and then to the DAO which I want to avoid.

I have my own mechanism to handle Authentication and Authorization. I need very simple solution to include this extra parameter in some context for each call to Service/DAO layers.

Note : I need a simple solution and don't want to use frameworks like spring-security etc.

Thank you in advance

Comment: AOP might help. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can consider using ThreadLocal. 
Set the username to ThreadLocal after authentication and get the value in the Service class.

Answer (score 1):

Hoping that you are using thread context, you can easily set a parameter in the context and use it anywhere inside the application. (much like session variables).
You can refer to this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-threadlocal) for assistance.
If you are already using spring sessions, then you set variables in session and make use of it.